# JQuery issue printing object to console.log

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I have written a function that iterates over array and returns object and its value if a match is found.

Somehow, when I call the function with its arguments, it always prints undefined on browser console.

Not sure what I am missing, but in function, when I console.log(v), I get the values, but not when calling the function.

HTML code:

```
<div class="accounts">
1<input name="1" value="" /><br>
2<input name="2" value="" /><br>
3<input name="3" value="" /><br>
4<input name="4" value="" /><br>
5<input name="5" value="" /><br>
6<input name="6" value="" /><br>
7<input name="7" value="" /><br>
8<input name="8" value="" /><br>
9<input name="9" value="" /><br>
10<input name="10" value="" /><br>
11<input name="11" value="" /><br>
</div>
```

JQuery code:

```
var vendor = [];
vendor = [{"vendor_id":"1","vendorname":"Coke","account_no":"34534554"},{"vendor_id":"2","vendorname":"Pepsi","account_no":"34634532"},{"vendor_id":"3","vendorname":"Dr. Pepper \/ 7 Up","account_no":"56754568"},{"vendor_id":"4","vendorname":"Frito Lay","account_no":"676554544"},{"vendor_id":"5","vendorname":"Blue Bunny","account_no":"678476543"},{"vendor_id":"6","vendorname":"Yummy","account_no":"9987654"},{"vendor_id":"7","vendorname":"Ork Farm","account_no":"23456767"},{"vendor_id":"8","vendorname":"Borden","account_no":"89765432"},{"vendor_id":"9","vendorname":"Highland","account_no":"2345678987"},{"vendor_id":"10","vendorname":"Nesquek","account_no":"798654324"}];

var getVendors = [];
$('.accounts input').each(function(){ 
    getVendors.push($(this).attr('name'));
});

function vendorAcctCheck (array, value) {
    array.filter(function(v) {
        if (v.vendor_id == value) {
            // console.log(v);
            return v;
        };
    })
    // return false;
}

var vendorData = vendorAcctCheck(vendor, "2");

console.log(vendorData)
```

Here is my JSFiddler [link](http://jsfiddle.net/swp6q73x/).

Comment: Note that you are using the return statement inside the callback for `array.filter`.

Comment: you missed a `return` for `array.filter`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forget to return.

You are using return only in filter's callback but that'll work only for `.filter` itself.

If you wanna to get filtered data,you have return the filtered data

Try like this

```
function vendorAcctCheck (array, value) {
   return array.filter(function(v) {
        if (v.vendor_id == value) {
            // console.log(v);
            return v;
        };
    })
    // return false;
}
```

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/ax183gbf/)